# Browser shows contents of index.html instead of the actual website

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, ftp, cpanel, filezilla

I just created my portfolio website which I made with bootstrap studio 2 and made some edits to the file once I exported it. When I load my site on my local host it loads just fine. But after I uploaded it via ftp (filezilla) the page does not fully load only the html and the bootstrap css. Has anyone ever experienced this and is there a solution?

Here's what it looks like on the web host:

[image: website on web host]

Here's what it looks like on localhost:

[image: website on local host]

Comment: I fetch this issue, did you got a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You're viewing the page through the file manager, so it just outputs the file content. You need to visit your index page through given (by your hosting) domain name (like `yourdomain.hobohost.com/index.html`).